# jQuery works on one server but not on the other

Tags: jquery

I have a strange problem and It would be highly appreciated if somebody could help me with this. Have been looking for hours now.

We created a test website for the company I work for.

See

```
http://socialmediabot.nl/html/
```

The website works as it should be.
When copying the website to the main host (different server)

```
https://www.aska-ltd.jp/
```

The javascript stops working. 
What could be the problem with this? 
Somehow on the new host it gives an error;

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Swiper is not defined ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/base.js:22:19)
    at l (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29567)
    at c (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:29869) undefined
w.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (base.js:22)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Anybody saw something like this before?

[update]

Could it be possible that there is something wrong with the server settings?

Comment: maybe you should use jQuery instead of jQuery Slim

Comment: Updated it, doesn't seems to be the problem.

Comment: When copying to another Server? So you put the same exact contents of htdocs into your root folder *(probably html/)* using FileZilla?

Comment: Yes Indeed. I don't know where it is going wrong. It seems that the server is changing characters by itself

Comment: If there are absolute paths that refer to the wrong page that could be the problem, but your error doesn't reflect that. If you used a CMS to build the site and there are databases involved there's a lot more to it.

Comment: I made it work with including the javascript from external servers. The problem is https on the server. There seems to be a conflict with it. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in js/swiper.min.js file. Check errors in console log of DevTools of your browser for details.

Try to replace it with content of according file from test server.

Comment: I wish that was the problem. I tried this; even including the swipper from the other server directly. This doesn't seem to work also.

Comment: Is there any js preprocessor on your site? Content of this file from test and real server is different. Compare http://socialmediabot.nl/html/js/swiper.min.js and https://www.aska-ltd.jp/js/swiper.min.js

Comment: Your real server uses https, so if you include scripts from another server it should also user https. Try https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Swiper/3.1.7

Comment: You are a legend! That did the trick. It was indeed the https problem. It is solved now. I love you right now! This took me so much time.